# Key Mapping Problems

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I play LOTRO and there is a UI for keymapping, but every time I insert where I want my maps they do not save, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you are clicking the Accept button at the bottom of the options panel when you're ready to save the updated mappings?  Just checking the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

More likely you have your config files in users/mydocuments/lord of the rings online/ read only. Check that